# trying to make an array getting new values through function, then return it as global

Tags: javascript, function

```
var doc = document;
var k;
var array1 = [];
var select = doc.getElementById("select");
var select = doc.getElementById("select");
var divP   = doc.getElementById("poeng" );
var divH   = doc.getElementById("helse" );
var runder = doc.getElementById("rundeQ");
var form1  = doc.getElementById("form1" );
form1.onsubmit = function(evt){ 
evt.preventDefault()
Window.k = array1.push("yay")
}
console.log(k)
```

---

what you are seeing is an attempt to make a global array that adds new values in function, i want to use this value later therefore trying to get that new array value available globally for the next functions aka making it globally. any tips how i can make it work? so the thing is i want to have multiple buttons that all returns thorugh function, to an array globally. then i can use the last value of everytime

Answer (score 0):

```
var doc = document;
var k;
var array1 = [];
var select = doc.getElementById("select");
var select = doc.getElementById("select");
var divP   = doc.getElementById("poeng" );
var divH   = doc.getElementById("helse" );
var runder = doc.getElementById("rundeQ");
var form1  = doc.getElementById("form1" );
form1.onsubmit = function(evt){ 
    evt.preventDefault()
    window.k = array1;
}
console.log(k)
```

You can use `window` object for this. Dont use `window.k = array1.push(value);`
Because [push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) returns length of the result array.

Comment: so i did this, but k still returns in console log "undefined" maybe it is because my, var k is already global? and even when i click that submit, it still wont show the value of k that is "added" throught the function and out

Comment: try console.log(window.k)

Comment: sorry it didnt work either, the var k outside the function overrides it of some kind, and placing it inside the function doesnt work either

Comment: can you check if the window is defined within your form1.onsubmit function? 
Can you also post the full code?